# Java - set value range

Tags: java

I am working on a Java 1.8 script in which I am trying to set a user input number range, in which user can only enter number between 0 and 1000. I am trying to set the range using the below code, but it is still allowing me (the user) to enter number greater than 1000.

```
} while (0 < digit && digit < 1000);
```

I tried searching for similar questions here, but a lot of answers I find basically recommend doing what I am doing below, and that seems to work for other users, so I don't understand why it is not working for me.

The code above is not throwing any errors, so I am baffled as to why it is still allowing me to enter number bigger than 1000. I am a Java novice so possibly some logic error...

This is my full code below. The purpose of the script is to enter number between 0 and 1000 and have the system calculate the sum of its digits. It is successfully calculating the sum, but when I enter a number greater than 1000, the sum is zero...

```
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and 1000.");
        int num = 4567;
        int sum = 0;
        while (num > 0 && num <1000) {
            sum = sum + num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the digits is " + sum);
```

Comment: Oops, that's what happens when my coffee runs out. I would think that you would want to repeat data capture if the data is *out* of range, not *inside* of range.

Comment: Better to post a [mcve] / [mre] with your question so we can see more of your pertinent code.

Comment: Seems like your condition is correct for your desired output, so the problem must lay somewhere else within your code. It would help to see all code related.

Comment: Did you want `} while (0 < digit && 1000 > digit);` It's hard to tell what you expect when you repeat the same single line of code three times. A MCVE would be helpful.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels "that's what happens when my coffee runs out" please don't bring up such harsh times in my life.. ;)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, good point...I put my whole code for clearer picture.

Comment: @JamieTaylorSangerman; , good point...I put my whole code for clearer picture.

Comment: The loop isn't even entered with posted code.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, isn't this the loop, since it is what is controlling the flow? } while (0 < digit && digit < 1000);

Comment: The only loop in your "whole code" is `while (num > 0 && num <1000) {` - and that loop is never entered, because `4567` is not less than `1000`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, what do you mean? I don't understand...

Comment: Which part? Your code sets `num` to `4567`, then read your while loop as "while num is greater than `0` **and** num is less than `1000` ..." Since `4567` is not less than `1000` the loop is not entered.

Answer (score 1):

To take user input, requiring it to be in the range of 1..999, you'll need something like this:

```
do {
    num = // get the input
} while (num < 1 || num > 999);
```

Your second loop is completely skipped if the number is 1000 or greater -- the sum will be the initial 0 for any such values. Maybe the second condition is not necessary at all -- it should work just fine for numbers of any size:

```
while (num > 0) {
    sum += num % 10;
    num /= 10;
}
```